# Real time object tracking in birds-eye in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, tracking

This program is my 'Real time Color Tracking in Birds-eye System'.

```
  #include <sstream>
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "Fruit.h"
  #include "opencv2\\opencv.hpp"

  #pragma comment(lib,"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\\opencv_core249d.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib,"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\\opencv_imgproc249d.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib,"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\\opencv_highgui249d.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib,"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\\opencv_objdetect249d.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib,"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\\opencv_ml249d.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib,"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\\opencv_video249d.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib,"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\\opencv_calib3d249d.lib")

  using namespace cv;
  //initial min and max HSV filter values.
  //these will be changed using trackbars
  int H_MIN = 0;
  int H_MAX = 256;
  int S_MIN = 0;
  int S_MAX = 256;
  int V_MIN = 0;
  int V_MAX = 256;
  //default capture width and height
  const int FRAME_WIDTH = 640;
  const int FRAME_HEIGHT = 480;
  //max number of objects to be detected in frame
  const int MAX_NUM_OBJECTS=50;
  //minimum and maximum object area
  const int MIN_OBJECT_AREA = 7*7;
  const int MAX_OBJECT_AREA = FRAME_HEIGHT*FRAME_WIDTH/1.5;
  //names that will appear at the top of each window
  const string windowName = "Original Image";
  const string windowName1 = "HSV Image";
  const string windowName2 = "Thresholded Image";
  const string windowName3 = "After Morphological Operations";
  const string trackbarWindowName = "Trackbars";

  void on_trackbar( int, void* )
  {
  //This function gets called whenever a
  // trackbar position is changed

  }

  string intToString(int number){

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << number;
  return ss.str();

  }

  void createTrackbars(){

  //create window for trackbars
  namedWindow(trackbarWindowName,0);
  //create memory to store trackbar name on window
  char TrackbarName[50];
  sprintf( TrackbarName, "H_MIN", H_MIN);
  sprintf( TrackbarName, "H_MAX", H_MAX);
  sprintf( TrackbarName, "S_MIN", S_MIN);
  sprintf( TrackbarName, "S_MAX", S_MAX);
  sprintf( TrackbarName, "V_MIN", V_MIN);
  sprintf( TrackbarName, "V_MAX", V_MAX);

  createTrackbar( "H_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &H_MIN, H_MAX, on_trackbar );
  createTrackbar( "H_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &H_MAX, H_MAX, on_trackbar );
  createTrackbar( "S_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &S_MIN, S_MAX, on_trackbar );
  createTrackbar( "S_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &S_MAX, S_MAX, on_trackbar );
  createTrackbar( "V_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &V_MIN, V_MAX, on_trackbar );
  createTrackbar( "V_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &V_MAX, V_MAX, on_trackbar );

  }

  void drawObject(vector<Fruit> theFruits,Mat &frame){

  for(int i =0; i<theFruits.size(); i++){

  cv::circle(frame,cv::Point(theFruits.at(i).getXPos(),theFruits.at(i).getYPos()),10,cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
  cv::putText(frame,intToString(theFruits.at(i).getXPos())+ " , " + intToString(theFruits.at(i).getYPos()),cv::Point(theFruits.at(i).getXPos(),theFruits.at(i).getYPos()+20),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0));
  }
  }

  void morphOps(Mat &thresh){

  //create structuring element that will be used to "dilate" and "erode" image.
  //the element chosen here is a 3px by 3px rectangle

  Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(3,3));
  //dilate with larger element so make sure object is nicely visible
  Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(8,8));

  erode(thresh,thresh,erodeElement);
  erode(thresh,thresh,erodeElement);

  dilate(thresh,thresh,dilateElement);
  dilate(thresh,thresh,dilateElement);

  }

  void trackFilteredObject(Mat threshold,Mat HSV, Mat &cameraFeed_BE){

  vector <Fruit> apples;

  Mat temp;
  threshold.copyTo(temp);
  //these two vectors needed for output of findContours
  vector< vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
  //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
  findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
  //use moments method to find our filtered object
  double refArea = 0;
  bool objectFound = false;
  if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
        int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
        //if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS we have a noisy filter
        if(numObjects<MAX_NUM_OBJECTS){
              for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {

                    Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
                    double area = moment.m00;

                    if(area>MIN_OBJECT_AREA){
                          Fruit apple;

                          apple.setXPos(moment.m10/area);
                          apple.setYPos(moment.m01/area);

                          apples.push_back(apple);

                          objectFound = true;

                    }else objectFound = false;


              }
              //let user know you found an object
              if(objectFound ==true){
                    //draw object location on screen
                    drawObject(apples,cameraFeed_BE);
              }

        }else putText(cameraFeed_BE,"TOO MUCH NOISE! ADJUST FILTER",Point(0,50),1,2,Scalar(0,0,255),2);
  }
  }

  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
  //if we would like to calibrate our filter values, set to true.
  bool calibrationMode = true;

  //Matrix to store each frame of the webcam feed
  Mat cameraFeed;
  Mat threshold;
  Mat HSV;

  if(calibrationMode){
        //create slider bars for HSV filtering
        createTrackbars();
  }
  //video capture object to acquire webcam feed
  VideoCapture capture;
  //open capture object at location zero (default location for webcam)
  capture.open(0);
  //set height and width of capture frame
  capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_WIDTH);
  capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,FRAME_HEIGHT);

  if(!capture.isOpened())  //confirm camera opened
  {
        return -1;
  }

  //start an infinite loop where webcam feed is copied to cameraFeed matrix
  //all of our operations will be performed within this loop
  while(1){

        do{
              capture >> cameraFeed;
        }while(cameraFeed.empty());

        int key = 0;
        IplImage* Frame ;
        IplImage* birds_image;
        CvMat *H;
        float Z; 

  cvNamedWindow("Birds eye");

  Frame =new IplImage(cameraFeed);
  birds_image = cvCloneImage(Frame);

  // EXAMPLE OF LOADING THESE MATRICES BACK IN:
  CvMat *intrinsic = (CvMat*)cvLoad("Intrinsics.xml");
  CvMat *distortion = (CvMat*)cvLoad("Distortion.xml");

  // Build the undistort map which we will use for all subsequent frames.
  IplImage* mapx = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(Frame), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
  IplImage* mapy = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(Frame), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
  cvInitUndistortMap(
        intrinsic,
        distortion,
        mapx,
        mapy
  );

  IplImage *t = cvCloneImage(Frame);
  //cvShowImage( "Calibration", image ); // Show raw image
  cvRemap( t, Frame, mapx, mapy );     // Undistort image
  cvReleaseImage(&t);

  H = (CvMat*)cvLoad("H.xml");

  cvWarpPerspective(
        Frame, 
        birds_image, 
        H, 
        CV_INTER_LINEAR | CV_WARP_INVERSE_MAP | CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS
        );

  cvShowImage("Birds eye", birds_image);

  Mat cameraFeed_BE = cvarrToMat(birds_image);

  //store image to matrix
  capture.read(cameraFeed_BE);
  //convert frame from BGR to HSV colorspace
  cvtColor(cameraFeed_BE,HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV);

  if(calibrationMode==true){
  //if in calibration mode, we track objects based on the HSV slider values.
  cvtColor(cameraFeed_BE,HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
  inRange(HSV,Scalar(H_MIN,S_MIN,V_MIN),Scalar(H_MAX,S_MAX,V_MAX),threshold);
  morphOps(threshold);

  imshow(windowName2,threshold);
  trackFilteredObject(threshold,HSV,cameraFeed_BE);
  }

  //show frames 
  imshow(windowName2,threshold);
  imshow(windowName,cameraFeed_BE);
  imshow(windowName1,HSV);

  //delay 30ms so that screen can refresh.
  //image will not appear without this waitKey() command
  if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
  }

  return 0;
  }
```

1. I think `Original Image`, `HSV Image` and `Thresholded Image` must
   be `birds image` but actually these aren't. I don't know why.
2. And I run the program for a minute, this Error appears.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9D12.png)

I think this error appears when there are some memory leak. SO I added this code.

```
  cvReleaseImage(&birds_image)
```

but this code didn't work well.

Could you give me your ideas regarding 1. and 2.?

Comment: You should avoid mixing legacy OpenCV functions like `cvReleaseImage` with new ones (like `cv::imshow`)... In fact you should avoid legacy OpenCV altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, the error message is related to an memory error. You have a memory allocation line

```
Frame =new IplImage(cameraFeed);
```

inside your infinite loop. This array (a RGB image from the webcam!!) is never released, and the loop writes over the pointer, losing the information and making it impossible to destroy that memory allocation.

Also, might be a good idea to move reading .xml files out of the infinite loop

```
CvMat *intrinsic = (CvMat*)cvLoad("Intrinsics.xml");
CvMat *distortion = (CvMat*)cvLoad("Distortion.xml");
```

Comment: I tried your ideas but the error also appears. Are there any odd programs ??

Comment: In general, I would suggest using cv::Mat instead of IplImage*. cv::Mat is a  smart pointer and releases its own memory. Firstly, this will help you reduce the number of awkward type casts that you are currently doing, as you are mixing the types. And, secondly, it is easier to see what memory you are allocating and what you are deallocating. Clearly, some of the IplImage* pointers are still allocated but never released.

Comment: Another point to your first question. You conduct various transformation and operations on the frame that you capture from the camera feed. You end up with    Mat cameraFeed_BE. On the next line of code after this you overwrite this array by capturing video again capture.read(cameraFeed_BE), I wonder if this is completely intentional.

Comment: "First Question" is solved by removing  "capture.read(cameraFeed_BE)". I'm mistakenly use "videocapture.read()" Thank you very much.

Comment: I think "cvInitUndistortMap", "cvRemap" and "cvWarpPerspective" function need "const cvArr*" so I converted "Mat cameraFeed" into  "IplImage* Frame". When I use cv::Mat, 'There isn't accurate convert-function from cv::Mat to cvArr*' appears.

Comment: When I used cvCapture instead of cvVideocapture, it can release image. So all problems are solved. thanks a lot !